# Is there a way to combine two tables in a view with nothing in common

Tags: mysql, join, union

I have a dilemma. I am trying to create one view for 2 different tables. The issue is that there is no common column for them to be joined or unioned.

**Table one**:

Table: `material`
Columns:

```
MaterialID int AI PK
MaterialDescription char(45)
MaterialSubDescription char(25)
AmountMaterialOnHand int
```

**Table two**:

Table: `wood`
Columns:

```
WoodID int AI PK
TypeOfWood char(25)
WoodOnHandInFeet int
```

I want to display the following columns in the view: `Description`, `SubDescription` and `AvailableAmount`.

I am trying to put `typeofwood` in the `Description` column and the `WoodOnHandInFeet` in the `Available` amount.
So the question of day is "How can I get this accomplished?" or do I need to do it different way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use a `UNION` as long as you select the same amount of columns from each, something like:

```
SELECT 
    MaterialDescription as 'Description', 
    MaterialSubDescription as 'SubDescription',
    AmountMaterialOnHand as 'AvailableAmount'
FROM
    material
UNION
SELECT 
    TypeOfWood as 'Description', 
    'WoodSubDescriptionOrEmptyStringOrNULLHereETC' as 'SubDescription',
    WoodOnHandInFeet as 'AvailableAmount'
FROM
    wood
```

Comment: @RPHennis I am glad I could help. If this is what you're looking for and is useful perhaps mark it as the correct answer/upvote.